# Return a boolean array of values < 40

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How can I get a boolean 1 dimentional output for values <40 from the below given array. Since there are three values <40 so the output should be: array([ True,  True,  True])

```
x = np.array([[40, 37, 70],[62, 61, 98],[65, 89, 22],[95, 98, 81],[44, 32, 79]])
```

Comment: Do you mean `[[True True False] [False False False] ...]`?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious `x < 40`?

Comment: @TimRoberts, The output needs to be exactly as  [True True True]

Comment: So, `[True] * (x < 40).sum()`?

Comment: You have 15 inputs.  How do you get 3 outputs?  Are you really just looking for the NUMBER of entries less than 40?  If so, what earthly good is an array of three booleans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[40, 37, 70],[62, 61, 98],[65, 89, 22],[95, 98, 81],[44, 32, 79]])
x<40
```

Output:

```
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]])
```

Or if you want a 1d result, you can use `.flatten()`:

```
y = x.flatten()
y<40
```

Output:

```
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False])
```

If you want a 1d list like `[True]*n` where n is the number of values `<40`, you can do:

```
np.array([i for i in x.flatten()<40 if i])
```

Output:

```
array([True, True, True])
```

Comment: Hi Nin17. Thanks for your reply. The output needs to be: [True True True]

Comment: so you want to count the number of values less than 40? ok, I've edited it to do that

Comment: Thank you again for sharp reply.The output needs to be an array. Yours is a list of boolean values if I am correct.

Comment: just do ```np.array([i for i in x.flatten()<40 if i])```, I've edited it

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved in many ways, one could be:

```
x[x<40]<40
```